# UIGesture Recognizer to specific area

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have scrollview that contain UIView, in which i have label with text. What i want is, to add tap gesture recognizer to dismiss view.

I tried following:

```
 /* Tap */

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap)];
    singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.mainScroll addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

    self.containerView = [UIView new];
    self.containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.mainScroll addSubview:self.containerView];
```

However, callback encounter when user tap anywhere on scroll (including view with text). How to prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `handleSingleTap` function get the touch location from the gesture, then use `CGRectContainsPoint` to see if the touch happened within a certain rect.  If it does, execute your dismiss, if not, ignore the touch.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding gestureRecognizer to scrollview. You can create a emty view where you want and add gestureRecognizer to it.

Answer (score -1):

Just get the Touch point from `UITapGestureRecognizer` callback and see if it happens in a certain `CGRect` or not.

```
- (void) handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [tapRecognizer locationInView:nil];
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(self.containerView.frame, touchPoint)) {
        //Tap Touch point is NOT on the container
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you ever read question? i need block to be called NOT when user tap container view.